# C, C++? How to compile

Tags: c++

I received the following piece of source code which generates a proprietary CRC value of an input string. Can you pls help to identify the language and suggest in which tool/environment can I compile and make it work. Thanks

```
WORD CalcCRC(BYTE *pstr, WORD len)
{
    AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState());
    WORD crc;
    WORD  i;
    crc = 0;                   // initialise CRC
    for (i = 0; i<len; i++)       // calculate CRC for every single byte
    {
        CRCBYT(*pstr, &crc);
        pstr++;
    }
    return crc;
}

void CRCBYT(unsigned char byt, WORD *pcrc)
{
    AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState());
    int i;
    WORD fl1;
    for (i = 0; i<8; i++)
    {
        fl1 = ((*pcrc) & 0x8000);  //MSB = 1?
        (*pcrc) <<= 1;               //CRC shift left
        if (byt & 0x80)            //MSB = 1?
            (*pcrc)++;               //Byte shift left
        byt <<= 1;
        if (fl1)                   //if fl1 XOR of CRC
            (*pcrc) ^= 0x1021;
    }
}
```

Comment: Suppose, you compiled it, what's next?

Answer (score 4):

It comes from Windows, but if you take out the `AFX_MANAGE_STATE` lines (which don't appear to be needed) it should compile in any C or C++ compiler.

You may need to add the following typedefs if you're not compiling for Windows:

```
 typedef unsigned short WORD;
 typedef unsigned char BYTE;
```